# Json.net custom converter of subobjects

Tags: c#, json, converters

Maybe this is related [c# json.net custom serialization of subobjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235973/c-sharp-json-net-custom-serialization-of-subobjects). But wasnt helping...

I want to deserialize a List to a data[,] while parsing, but the converter does not want to work. And data[,] is a member of a class.
Does i need to add the converter to JsonProperty? Does i really need both converters?

At the moment i got this:
Unexpected token when deserializing multidimensional array: StartObject. Path '[0]', line 2, position 3.
A search wasnt helping :/

My Code:

Program.cs

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

public class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jss.Converters.Add(new MyObjectJsonConverter());
        MyObject field = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(File.ReadAllText("data.json").ToString(), jss);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

MyObject.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyObject {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "area", Required = Required.Always)]
    public area m_area;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "datalist", Required = Required.Always)]
    public data[,] m_datalist;
}
```

data.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class data {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "info", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string m_info;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "info2", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string m_info2;
    }
```

area.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class area {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "x", Required = Required.Always)]
    public int m_x;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "y", Required = Required.Always)]
    public int m_y;
}
```

And both converters.

MyObjectJsonConverter.cs

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class MyObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return objectType == typeof(MyObject);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        MyObject result = new MyObject();

        result.m_area = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<area>(jObject["area"].ToString());

        JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jss.Converters.Add(new DataListJsonConverter(result.m_area.m_x, result.m_area.m_y));
        result.m_datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<data[,]>(jObject["datalist"].ToString(), jss);

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

DataListJsonConverter.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DataListJsonConverter : JsonConverter {
    private readonly int m_x;
    private readonly int m_y;

    public DataListJsonConverter(int x, int y) {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return objectType == typeof(List<data>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        data[,] tilesArray = new data[m_x, m_y];

        foreach (JToken token in jObject["datalist"]) {
            data curTile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<data>(token.ToString());
            tilesArray[(int) token["x"], (int) token["y"]] = curTile;
        }

        return tilesArray;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and the data.json

```
{
    "area": {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 10
    },
    "datalist": [
        {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 2, 
            "info": "test1",
            "info2": "test1"
        },
        {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 5, 
            "info": "test2",
            "info2": "test2"
        },
        {
            "x": 5,
            "y": 7, 
            "info": "test3",
            "info2": "test3"
        },
        {
            "x": 6,
            "y": 4, 
            "info": "test4",
            "info2": "test4"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: couple of questions : 1) why are you suing multidimensional array here data[,]? the json looks like it's plain one dimensional array. 2) and are you using "data" & "data2" fields in the json string on purpose or you meant to say "info" & "info2"?

Comment: I need to convert it into an 2D array for further using the data. The x and y of the objects in the array will used as index. 2. yes my fault. I correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor changes to DataListJsonConvert might do the trick here :

update the can convert method to check for what you are attempting to deserialize to

```
public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
    {
        return objectType == typeof( data[,] );
    }
```

and in your ReadJson implementation read the json content as JArray instead of JObject

```
public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        JArray jArray = JArray.Load( reader );

        data[,] tilesArray = new data[m_x, m_y];

        foreach( JToken token in jArray )
        {
            data curTile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<data>( token.ToString() );
            tilesArray[(int) token["x"], (int) token["y"]] = curTile;
        }

        return tilesArray;
    }
```

and I think this should give you the multidimensional array structure you are looking for.